# Configure php-fpm to access environment variables in docker

Tags: php-fpm, docker, environment-variables, docker-compose

I'm running php7-fpm in a docker container. However my php scripts aren't able to access environments variables set in my docker-compose file. `getenv('MY_ENV_VAR')` returns `FALSE`.

I've changed `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` to include `clear_env = no` and restarted with `service php7.0-fpm restart` but my environment variables start aren't there.

I've also tried editing /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini includes the line `variables_order = "EGPCS"`.

When I exec into my container on a bash shell I can see that my variables exist. It's just that they're not accessible in my php scripts.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11):

This is a PHP-FPM prank.

- Setup the `clear_env = no` on `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`, so;

On Dockerfile start de php-fpm with `init.d`, **not use** `service`.
Ex:

```
CMD /etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm start && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Check environment variables now

Comment: Wtf this actually worked, what the fuck php-fpm

Comment: It's working, dude. Why is it possible? Any references?

Answer (score 2):

Well this seems all wrong but I've got it working by adding the environment variables in a bash script -

```
#!/bin/bash    
echo "" >> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf # new line.
if ! [ -z "$MY_ENV_VAR" ]
then
    echo "env[MY_ENV_VAR] = $MY_ENV_VAR;" >>  /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
fi
```

Then in my Dockerfile -

```
COPY add_env_vars.sh /add_env_vars.sh
CMD source /add_env_vars.sh && service php7.0-fpm start
```

It looks like php-fpm just doesn't play well with system environment variables.

For more info see -

- [This docker issue](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/74)
- [This (more comprehensive) workaround](http://l33t.peopleperhour.com/2014/03/13/setting-environment-variables-in-php-fpm-when-using-docker-links/)

Comment: Or you could have just used the simple `clear_env = no` which ought to be set in the container image already, but isn't because that guy doesn't understand it.

Comment: Setting `clear_env=no` before starting php-fpm didn't work for me. The env var's still weren't available.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - thanks for your input. Am I missing something? The first thing I did was set `clear_env=no` in my container image. I didn't include that information in order to keep my question concise. (I stated that doing the same thing more directly didn't work - i.e. I exec'd into the container and ran the commands in a bash shell). Apologies if that wasn't clear - please do let me know if I'm still missing something.

Comment: This is pretty old but clear_env does not work on RHEL based distros last I heard - That would explain the confusion here @MichaelHampton

Comment: @MichaelHampton My apologies... pretty rude though for a mod though don't you think? I guess I can explain why I left a comment:

1) In my cursory glance I didn't notice anything directly attributing this to Debian or RHEL 

2) It's a pretty commonly known issue that clear_env really only works on debian based systems - This guy claimed that it didn't work and I was leaving a comment for future visitors in case they found this thread with the same issue (the same way I did)

Have a great day and I apologize for tagging you with information!

Comment: I can confirm that clear_env = no absolutely isn't working for me on ubuntu